# Divorce and separation circumstances in Georgia

Tags: divorce, georgia

My marriage is experiencing tough times and the divorce issue has already been arisen for a couple of times. It's not the first time when my wife wants to file a divorce, however the first time we agreed upon a legal separation and that worked out. Now we have been living in Atlanta for 14 months and both are up to a divorce. My wife moved out about a week ago and I have recently found out that legal separation is not an option in Georgia. So my question is under which circumstances is it legally possible to file a divorce in Georgia, taking into consideration the fact that we are living separately for about a week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this https://gaonlinedivorce.com/moving-from-legal-separation-in-georgia-to-filing-a-divorce/ article it is necessary to reside in GA for more than 6 months and it is possible to file a divorce only after a separation period according to Georgia legislation. Here what they say:"In fact, a husband and wife are supposed to stop their marital relations with intent to get divorced any time soon. Spouses can be considered separated even if they continue living under the same roof. Moreover, they are not required to draft any agreement" So basically you are able to file a divorce within 1 month of being separated.